# How to cleanup mempool

Tags: bitcoind, mempool

I want to cleanup mempool.
I googled and knew -zapwallettxes might clean up mempool.

But when I do the following command, mempool is still loaded.

> ./bitcoind -testnet=3 -server -rest -dbcache=4000 -txindex=1 -rpcbind=0.0.0.0 -rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0 -printtoconsole -zapwallettxs=2 -rescan

In this situation, even if I restart bitcoind, mempool is dumped to .bitcoin/testnet3/mempool.dat and loaded on startup.

how should I clean up mempool?

Any comments and advices are welcomed :)

Comment: Have you tried using the option `maxmempool=N`, where N is the maximum size of your mempool in megabytes?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  What do you hope to accomplish by "cleaning up" the mempool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, clearing your mempool doesn't really do anything if the transactions you're clearing have already propagated through the network. The mempool will sync again when you connect to other peers.

`mempool.dat` was introduced in `0.14.0` and will persist the mempool on shutdown. In order to clear the mempool you have to:

1. Shutdown Bitcoin Core `$ bitcoin-cli -testnet3 stop`
2. Delete mempool.dat `$ rm ~/.bitcoin/testnet3/mempool.dat`
3. Restart the daemon `$ bitcoind -testnet -zapwallettxes`

**Note:** You might also need start the daemon with `-zapwallettxes` so the transactions related to your wallet aren't loaded into the mempool at startup.

**Another Note**: If you only want to remove transactions related to your wallet, you can skip step 2: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/10330

Comment: `-zapwallettxes` has been removed from bitcoin-core. Use `abandontransaction` to clear an orphaned Tx from the wallet.